# Creating cascading dropdownlist from a json

Tags: javascript, asp.net, model-view-controller

We are working on an HR project, and I want to retrieve city, district, and neighborhood information from a JSON file I found on the internet, and connect them with each other while saving employee records. I am getting the JSON data through a controller and sending it to the view with a view model. However, I haven't been able to establish the connection between them. Can you help me with how to do this?

This is the json data where i get the data:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nejdetkadir/il-ilce-semt-mahalleler/master/data/data.json

```
public class AddressController : Controller
{
    List<AddressData> addressData = new List<AddressData>();
    public IActionResult GetAllAddresses()
    {
        var model = new AddressViewModel();

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nejdetkadir/il-ilce-semt-mahalleler/master/data/");
            var response = client.GetAsync("data.json");
            response.Wait();
            var result = response.Result;

            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var readTask = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                readTask.Wait();
                var readData = readTask.Result;
                addressData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AddressData>>(readData);
            }
        }

        model.Cities = addressData.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.Name, Text = x.Name }).ToList();
        
        model.Towns = addressData.SelectMany(x => x.Towns)
             .Select(town => new SelectListItem { Value = town.Name, Text = town.Name })
             .ToList();
        
        model.Districts = addressData.SelectMany(x => x.Towns)
                 .SelectMany(town => town.Districts)
                 .Select(district => new SelectListItem { Value = district.Name, Text = district.Name })
                 .ToList();
        
        model.Quarters = addressData.SelectMany(x => x.Towns)
                .SelectMany(town => town.Districts)
                .SelectMany(district => district.Quarters)
                .Select(quarter => new SelectListItem { Value = quarter.Name, Text = quarter.Name })
                .ToList();

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should only load cities in 1st call. On change event of cities, call another method which will get you list of all towns for selected city, so on and so forth. I would prefer to do this with JavaScript / jQuery instead of doing this in backend code, since you are already calling a public JSON.

1. Fetch and read JSON on JavaScript onload
2. Fill cities from client side itself
3. Create onchange function in JavaScript for city and load towns for that city
4. Follow same approach, pass selected city and town and get districts and so on